# BLE functionality is not called

Tags: android, list, nullpointerexception, bluetooth-lowenergy

My code is:

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity/*ListActivity*/ {
    //private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;
    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    UsersAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //getActionBar().setTitle("abc");

        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Use this check to determine whether BLE is supported on the device.  Then you can
        // selectively disable BLE-related features.
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.ble_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        // Initializes a Bluetooth adapter.  For API level 18 and above, get a reference to
        // BluetoothAdapter through BluetoothManager.
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        // Checks if Bluetooth is supported on the device.
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_bluetooth_not_supported, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }


        // Construct the data source

        ArrayList<ViewHolder> arrayOfUsers = new ArrayList<ViewHolder>();

       // Create the adapter to convert the array to views

         adapter = new UsersAdapter(this, arrayOfUsers);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        scanLeDevice(true);
        ViewHolder newUser2 = new ViewHolder("adtv2","vvg2");
         adapter.add(newUser2);

    }


    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
            ViewHolder newUser2 = new ViewHolder("adtv2","vvg2");
            adapter.add(newUser2);
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mScanning = false;
                    mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    //invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            mScanning = true;
            mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        } else {
            mScanning = false;
            mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
        }
        //invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }



    // Device scan callback.
    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            //mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            //ViewHolder newUser = new ViewHolder("Nathan", "San Diego");
                            String deviceName=null, deviceAddress=null;
                            if(device!=null)
                               deviceName= device.getName();
                            if (!(deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0))
                                deviceName = "unknown device";
                            if(device!=null)
                                deviceAddress= device.getAddress();
                            ViewHolder newUser = new ViewHolder(deviceName, deviceAddress);
                            ViewHolder newUser2 = new ViewHolder("adtv","vvg");
                            adapter.add(newUser2);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
    public class UsersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ViewHolder> {

        public UsersAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ViewHolder> users) {

            super(context, 0, users);

        }



        @Override

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Get the data item for this position

            ViewHolder user = getItem(position);

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view

            if (convertView == null) {

                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.bt_details, parent, false);

            }

            // Lookup view for data population

            TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DeviceName);

            TextView tvHome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.DeviceAddress);

            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object

            tvName.setText(user.deviceName);

            tvHome.setText(user.deviceAddress);

            // Return the completed view to render on screen

            return convertView;

        }

    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        String deviceName;
        String deviceAddress;

        public ViewHolder(String device, String __address) {
            this.deviceName =device;
            this.deviceAddress= __address;
        }
    }

}


**I am trying to list the available Bluetooth devices after scan.
```

This method is not getting called I suppose.because the listview prints only 2 messages .it should  print3 for working properly
the code in LeScanCallback does not print, so I guess this code is not called.So, the bluetooth functionality is not working.**

```
bt_details.xml->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DeviceName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DeviceAddress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address" />

    </LinearLayout>

listitem_device.xml:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <!--   <TextView android:id="@+id/device_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24dp"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/device_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12dp"/>-->
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

main.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--tools:context=".ListActivity" -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

listitem.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

BLUETOOTH discovery is problem I guess.I have pasted the code and the layout xml files

Comment: can you please share the crash log also ?

Comment: where I will getthe crash log?Iam running on phone.My PC is notrunning emulator.It is a linux PC.It hangs

Comment: Your using androis studio,right ?

Comment: yes android studio

Comment: Then you can see the crash  logs in  logcat window.

Comment: The stack trace points to commented out code - setTitle(). Can you uncomment what crashes the app and then post the relevant stacktrace? It doesn’t seem to be in sync with the source code. Also, if you need to go back and forth with @Madcode, you should use the chat option, resolve the issue there and then mark the answer.

Comment: Hi,I faced 1 more problem , could you help me in that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong layout for a `ListActivity`, and it seems you copied one of the online examples and tried to modify it to do something it wasn't meant for (dynamic data)

I suggest you change

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends ListActivity
```

To

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

And remove `setListAdapter` method.

Then use your main layout

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);  // here
```

Then, this data will work fine

```
        String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
                "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.listitem, mobileArray);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**But** you want to add bluetooth devices, so **delete all that** (or least, make sure it works, first), and instead make a different Adapter, probably a custom one - [start here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView), and read down through "Using a Custom ArrayAdapter" section.

For example `public class LeDeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter< BluetoothDevice>`

If that is the adapter that is a field of your activity

```
public class DeviceScanActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter; // This here
```

Then, this code should work

```
// in onCreate
mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
```

And setup your listener to just use the built-in add method

```
// Device scan callback.
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mLeDeviceListAdapter.add(device);
                    }
                });
            }
        };
```

Comment: I never used `R.id.list` in my answer. Remove it

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION);
private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 456;

@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // Permission granted, yay! Start the Bluetooth device scan.
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                } else {
                    // Alert the user that this application requires the location permission to perform the scan.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

andchanged minSdkVersion in build.gradle to 23
NOW BLE scanning works fine